# 403 forbidden errors being served only for some users on some content

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I have a VPS running Debian 7, with Virtualmin 4.12gpl and a very vanilla configuration of Apache 2.2.22, PHP 5.4.35 and MySQL 5.5.40 with WordPress 4.01.

I'm experiencing a very odd issue in which certain resources (images and stylesheets, for example) are generating 403 errors for some users and not for others.

For example, some users get a 403 when trying to load this stylesheet: http://lunchtime.org.uk/wp-content/themes/GLA5/style.css (I don't!)

Some users get a 403 when trying to load this image: http://lunchtime.org.uk/wp-content/themes/GLA5/img/podcast.png (I do!)

I've tried a few things:

- Changing the permissions has no effect. I've even set it to 777 and the offending files still won't load. Additionally, I can see and download the files through FTP.
- I thought mod_security might be the issue, but is not installed
- The .htaccess file looks normal for a WordPress installation.
- Disabling caching\permalink-related plugins, and clearing my own cache doesn't do anything
- Using virtualmin's 'Fix file ownership and permissions' button does nothing.

I've also tried running (as an example)

```
chown -R www-data:www-data podcast.png
```

manually, but it has no effect.

It might be worth mentioning that I've set up the same site on two other VPSes, in the same way, and it worked just fine. I migrated all the content to this server on monday, just by copying all the files by FTP and doing a database export\import in phpMyAdmin.

Here's the .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I won't post the whole apache error log here, but every single error looks like this:

```
[Fri Nov 21 00:09:21 2014] [crit] [client 141.101.98.168] (13)Permission denied: /home/lunchtime/public_html/wp-content/themes/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

Thank you.

Comment: bulletproof security is probably changing .htaccess to 440, change it to 640.

Comment: the error is permissions for the htaccess file, not the content. Apache needs to be able to read it.

Answer (score 0):

nvm figured it out

...I kid, I kid!

There was a recent update to apache that changed the syntax of the FilterProvider directive. As it turns out, the version of the HTML5 boilerplate .htaccess file I was using was using the old syntax.

If you're encountering this problem, open up your .htaccess file and do a search for

```
FilterProvider
```

According to [this Github Comment](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1012) (whose instructions I followed), you should change any line that looks like this:

```
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/html
```

Into this:

```
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'text/html'"
```